# Keep the button active until I click another button (Without affecting all website buttons)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have 3 Buttons

```
<li><a class="btn btn-sm mb-3 getnowbutton getnowbutton1" href="#" data-toggle="tab">3 Months</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm mb-3 getnowbutton getnowbutton1" data-toggle="tab">6 Months</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm mb-3 getnowbutton getnowbutton1" data-toggle="tab">1 Year</a></li>
```

I want to keep the button I click active until I click another one, But only for this 3 buttons without affecting all web page buttons.

I've tried

```
.getnowbutton1:focus{
background-color: white;
color: red;}
```

But when I click anywhere on the page It won't be focused anymore.

Any ideas ?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, Sorry.

Comment: you have to intercept the click event and stop it from propagating using stopPropagation() and preventDefault() and use if statement to add you condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class called `active` and use `jquery` to add this class to the clicked link (and remove from the others).

See this working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.getnowbutton').click(function(){
    $('.getnowbutton').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><a class="btn btn-sm mb-3 getnowbutton getnowbutton1" href="#" data-toggle="tab">3 Months</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm mb-3 getnowbutton getnowbutton1" data-toggle="tab">6 Months</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm mb-3 getnowbutton getnowbutton1" data-toggle="tab">1 Year</a></li>
```